# Rasterio/GDAL read and write modified data

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to read and write from the same data set. As data gets modified there are situations where that data needs to be read and modified again, immediately. The python code looks pretty straight forward, but it seems to be buffering the writes to disk, but not in the same memory location as the reads because those seem to be writing different data??

```
with rasterio.open("mydata.tiff", "r+") as rIoHandle:
    # Read window
    data = rIoHandle.read(1, window=myWindow) 
    # Modify data
    data = data * 0.9
    # Write back window
    rIoHandle.write(data, window=myWindow)
```

It seems like as that window is re-read it's actually just reading the original data, not the data that is written. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a write thread in the background that is hiding that data from me?

Thanks,
-Seth

Comment: In my experience with rasterio/GDAL, data is usually only written to disk once you **close the file**. Why would you want to write the modified data, read it again right away, just to modify it again? Either way, you have to close the file to write.

Comment: Not enough memory to store everything in memory at once. This is a 3mo old question. I don't even know what this was in reference to, I think I found a workaround (I don't remember) but I'll leave this open in case anyone else has any ideas.